# Change the class of a Button element to show/hide it

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, css-selectors

I am trying to show or hide a button element based on certain criteria in my code.  I have made the button's default css to "hide" it with `display: none`, then to add a class that changes the display to `display: block`.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button id="show">SHOW</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#show {
  display: none;
}

#show .visible {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
var d = document.getElementById('show');
d.className += "visible";
```

I have also tried:

```
var d = document.getElementById('show');
d.classList.add("visible");
```

As well as:

```
documnet.getElementById('show').classList.add('visible');
```

The problem is that I can't get the class to apply properly, and won't display the button when the class is updated.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, just not sure what it is if someone can assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're putting the class "visible" on the same element that has the id "show".

So in your CSS there should not be a space between the #show and .visible.

HTML

```
<div>
  <button id="show">SHOW</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #show {
  display: none;
}

#show.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
var d = document.getElementById('show');
d.classList.add("visible");
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this method!

Instead of changing the ID's toggle the class `hide` so that the button is visible or invisible!

```js
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("show");
    element.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}

#show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="show">SHOW</button>
</div>
<button onClick="myFunction()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: It's not an 'on-click' function though, and it is based off of a certain line of code running to require the button to become visible.

Comment: @BaracudaBill Yes, I did that for demonstration purpose! But please toggle the class `hide` to hide the element, you can use any method but `element.classList.toggle("hide");` this can be used to toggle the class!

Comment: @NarenMurali is right thouth. simply create a css class called `.hidden` which has `display:none`. Apply that class in the html. Then simply toggle it on and off with `classList.toggle` or you can use `classList.add /remove`.

Comment: I appreciate your input, thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

**Simple.** Write this:

```
#show.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Instead of:

```
#show .visible {
  display: block;
}
```

*(Just **remove the space** you put between **#show** and **.visible**)*

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('show').classList.add('visible');
```

```css
#show {
  /*display: none;*/
}
.invisible{
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="show" class="invisible">SHOW</button>
</div>
```

I'd like to recommend using 2 classes. `.visible`, `.invisible`.

You should set `display:none` on `.invisible`. not `#show`.